# Communication between browser (javascript) and java App

Tags: javascript, java, html, websocket

I'm working in a project where I need print documents from an html webpage, I made a JAVA app to Communicate with my printer and it works, but I need integrate that app with javascript to print documents.

Something like an applet would work but applets were depreciated, I think that I can use something like websockets but I'm not sure how it would be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: suppose this is a good [post](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) to refer to start your application. also refer [this](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere).

Comment: what is wrong with a good ol` servlet?

Comment: I have a client-server app with html-javascript in frontend, if I use a servlet I would need another server (apache tomcat) for run it, i think